# IPv4 over IPv6 tunnel for HughesNet user

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, tunneling

I have a client who wants to access cameras remotely via a HughesNET Internet connection. HughesNET using carrier grade NATting (CGN) for IPv4 and so does not provide their customers with publicly routable IPv4 addresses. They do, however, provide publicly routable IPv6 (although, these are dynamic, they occasionally change the prefixes... grrr).

The client's DVR does not support remote viewing over IPv6. I'm looking for the easiest way to work around this problem. My current idea is to put a Rasberry Pi on site and setup a IPv4 over IPv6 tunnel between the pi and a cloud VPS and basically reverse proxy the services through the tunnel to the VPS. Client could then go to the VPS via IPv4 to access his cameras.

Does this sound like a plausible solution? Is there an easier alternative I'm missing? Anyone done something similar and could provide me with some details? This is at the edge of my networking knowledge. I'm particularly concerned about how to deal with the changing IPv6 addresses on the HughesNET connection.

Comment: Does it need to be available to the public?  Have you considered just establishing a VPN to the network?  Perhaps by running OpenVPN or something on that RasberryPi?

Comment: Does not need to be publicly available (although they do need access from mobile devices)--I understand that the satellite modems due some strange things to accelerate the data stream and simulate lower latency and that the VPN might interfere with?

Comment: The mobile devices will almost certainly have IPv6. Another problem is the upload speed from the HughesNet site, and the data limits placed by HughesNet, which has a clause in the contract preventing this type of thing (no servers to the Internet allowed).

Comment: Problem for OpenVPN is this: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/498

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly put up a NAT64 gateway on the customer premises. Tayga, for example, will run on a Raspberry Pi or similar small hardware, or even in a VM on an existing server. This will make the cameras accessible via IPv6, and thus available on mobile devices. Now, if the cameras require proprietary software to access them, and it only speaks IPv4, then all bets are off.

As a long term matter, your customer should complain to the camera manufacturer about the lack of IPv6 support and his willingness to buy cameras from some other manufacturer in the future because of this.